# VBA Access multiple replace

Tags: vba

I have a table master with a memo field. This fileld content many abreviation of full text. The full text is on another table call nomemclature.

I want to make a multiple replace from the nomemclature table to the master table with the correspondant field.

I also have some problem with the abreviation field. The field has many error like space ans other caractere that l want not to replace.

How can i do the thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code below. Use it as in the Test procedure. In the first recordset, supply the one field you want to process. In the secord recordset, supply the two fields for find and replace.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim oRSetToProcess As Recordset
    Dim oRSetFindReplace As Recordset

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    Set oRSetToProcess = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [MemoField] FROM [tblData];")
    Set oRSetFindReplace = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Find],[Replace] FROM [tblFindReplace];")

    BulkReplace oRSetToProcess, oRSetFindReplace

    oRSetToProcess.close
    oRSetFindReplace.close

    Set oRSetToProcess = Nothing
    Set oRSetFindReplace = Nothing

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub

Public Sub BulkReplace(oRSetToProcess As Recordset, oRSetFindReplace As Recordset)

    Dim sTempString As String

    oRSetToProcess.MoveFirst

    Do Until oRSetToProcess.EOF
        sTempString = oRSetToProcess(0)
        oRSetFindReplace.MoveFirst
        Do Until oRSetFindReplace.EOF
            sTempString = Replace(sTempString, oRSetFindReplace(0), oRSetFindReplace(1))
            oRSetFindReplace.MoveNext
        Loop
        With oRSetToProcess
            .Edit
            .Fields(0) = sTempString
            .Update
            .MoveNext
        End With
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will try

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your help.